# Basic Probability Question: Ordered Sample With Replacement (Help!)

Tags: probability

Each time a fair die is tossed a marker is moved 10 cm east, west, north or south if the die shows 1, 2, 3, or 4 respectively. If the die shows a 5 or a 6 the marker is not moved. What is the probability that the marker is at its original position after three moves? A detailed solution will be very much appreciated!

Are there 3^6 possible outcomes for this die? Do I then just write down all the outcomes that will cause the marker to remain in its original position e.g. {152,364,...}

Comment: A discussion of your tries will be very much appreciated!!

Comment: I assume you mean $3$ tosses, else probability is $0$.

Comment: I said tosses regarding the die and moved regarding the marker...

Comment: @LeonLeibovici "Position after three moves" you cannot mean three moves of the marker (because this would trivially be probability 0) you must mean "three rolls of the die"

Comment: You're right. Can you provide me with a solution or tell me at least if I'm on the right track?

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Comment: no it is 6^3 (not 3^6) and that is only 216 possibilities so just enumerate them is easy,(hardly worthwhile to check for permutations)

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at how we can get a winning set of three rolls:

1. If we roll anything but $5,6$ first, then there are three acceptable second rolls ($5,6$ and the number which undoes what we did on our first roll).

   - If our second role was $5$ or $6$, then there is only one acceptable option for the final roll, whatever undoes our first roll. Giving $\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$.
   - If our second role was whatever undid the first roll, then we have two options for the final roll, $5$ or $6$. Giving $\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$
2. If we roll a $5$ or $6$ first everything is acceptable on our second roll.

   - If we rolled a $5$ or $6$ on the second roll we have two options for the third roll, $5$ or $6$. Giving us $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$.
   - If we rolled anything else on the second roll we have one option for the third roll. Giving us $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$

This looks like it gives us $\frac{4}{27}$

Comment: I worked out that their was 6^3=216 permutations for three rolls of the die. And listed all the outcomes that leave the marker at its original position after all three movies (=32). 32/216=2/27. Took about 3/4 minutes - not too time consuming.